# Why jQuery Select box change event is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on product filters where user select from the select box according to his/her preference but I am not getting selected value by user in jQuery.

html code:

```
<select name="product_filter" id="product_filter">
        <option value="price_low_first">Price : Low to High</option>
        <option value="price_high_first">Price : High to Low</option>
        <option value="latest">Latest</option>
        <option value="popular">Most Popular</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
        $("#product_filter").change(function () {
          alert("hi")
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It works https://jsfiddle.net/qbkfm1eh/  So what is your issue??? Are you sure change event is bound?! Is this `select` element added after DOM is ready? Etc...

Comment: Does your select box is populated in DOM after page get loaded initially?

Comment: @RahulPatel select box is loaded manually.. it is not loaded by any code..

Comment: @A.Wolff i found this in console error... can this be a problem?

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: And are you sure you have placed jquery before your onchange event?

Comment: @RahulPatel yes, i have initialized all js files before this js code

Comment: @WebFlash That's a warning, not an error... Now at least try delegating event: `$(document).on('change', "#product_filter", function(){...});`

Comment: @A.Wolff i have a console error..

http://localhost/lifetech/resources/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

But i have that file ready there.. i have checked twice

Comment: Wait, before we continue and to avoid you make me more waste my time, any other errors in console??? What part of previous error message don't you understand? You obviously don't correctly includ jQuery, so what are you expecting?!  I'm french, it easy for me to give up... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry for wasting your time...
But there is no more error...
and i really did correctly include jQuery...
I have added 11 more js files which is working fine, but i don't know what the hell is the problem with jQuery..
I have tried all the different version.. but in everything it doesn't work..
All other things which was designed with jQuery like cart and popup is working fine though it is giving me an error...

Comment: Ya strange. Any online link we can check?

Comment: sure.. @A.Wolff
Check it here..
https://i.imgsafe.org/3c3d110c62.png

https://i.imgsafe.org/3c3d1e142b.png

Comment: I'm really sorry but i'm out of idea. Your posted code and screenshot seem clean, i don't see any issue. Clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah thank you for the time and help.. :)

I also have never seen such kind of error in my life

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe that your code is perfect. Once please check jquery.min.js is included in your file. Please check if there are any console errors.Thank you.

Comment: hello,
i have a console error of missing file but file is there already, when i click that link on error i see that file and all code there in developer tools